# Parse Cloud is not returning image

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have spent over 3 days on getting the Image File from Parse Cloud. But Its returning nothing. I have checked the backend the data has been added there but it doesn't return the images. Can some angel help me out with this?

```
 // Set up a customized query
        ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<AnywallPost> factory =
                new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<AnywallPost>() {
                    public ParseQuery<AnywallPost> create() {
                        Location myLoc = (currentLocation == null) ? lastLocation : currentLocation;
                        ParseQuery<AnywallPost> query = AnywallPost.getQuery();
                        query.include("user");
                        query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                        query.include("image");
                        query.whereWithinKilometers("location", geoPointFromLocation(myLoc), radius
                                * METERS_PER_FEET / METERS_PER_KILOMETER);
                        query.setLimit(MAX_POST_SEARCH_RESULTS);
                        return query;
                    }
                };

        // Set up the query adapter
        postsQueryAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<AnywallPost>(this, factory) {
            @Override
            public View getItemView(AnywallPost post, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (view == null) {
                    view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.anywall_post_item, null);
                }
                ParseFile photo = (ParseFile) post.get("image");
                TextView contentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content_view);
                image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.picture_view);
                imageloader.DisplayImage(post.getPhoto(),image);
                TextView usernameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username_view);
                contentView.setText(post.getText());
                usernameView.setText(post.getUser().getUsername());
                post.setPhoto(photo.getUrl());
                return view;
            }
        };
```

Edited Verison :

```
  // Set up a customized query
        ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<AnywallPost> factory =
                new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<AnywallPost>() {
                    public ParseQuery<AnywallPost> create() {
                        Location myLoc = (currentLocation == null) ? lastLocation : currentLocation;
                        ParseQuery<AnywallPost> query = AnywallPost.getQuery();
                        query.include("user");
                        query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                        query.whereWithinKilometers("location", geoPointFromLocation(myLoc), radius
                                * METERS_PER_FEET / METERS_PER_KILOMETER);
                        query.setLimit(MAX_POST_SEARCH_RESULTS);
                        return query;
                    }
                };

        // Set up the query adapter
        postsQueryAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<AnywallPost>(this, factory) {
            @Override
            public View getItemView(AnywallPost post, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (view == null) {
                    view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.anywall_post_item, null);
                }
                ParseFile photo = (ParseFile) post.get("image");
                if (photo != null) {
                    photo.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            if (data != null && e == null) {
                                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                                        .decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                                                data.length);
                                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                            } else {
                                //ParseException e
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    //picture_not_available
                }
                TextView contentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content_view);
                image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.picture_view);
                TextView usernameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username_view);
                contentView.setText(post.getText());
                usernameView.setText(post.getUser().getUsername());
                post.setPhoto(photo.getUrl());
                return view;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get image resources using `getDataInBackground`

```
if (photo != null) {
                photo.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (data != null && e == null) {
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                                    .decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                                            data.length);
                            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                        } else {
                            //ParseException e
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                //picture_not_available
            }
```

Comment: In which scope should I add the code? @kishore jethava

Comment: after  `ParseFile photo = (ParseFile) post.get("image");`

Comment: should i remove query.include('image') from QueryAdapter ?

Comment: Should I also remove the post.setPhoto(photo.getUrl());

Comment: post `setPhoto();` func. yes if it setting image

Comment: Thanks a lot? Are you on any IM chat? May be we can keep in touch there

Comment: kishore.jethava @Skype

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99515/discussion-between-kishore-jethava-and-sagar-atalatti).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way its work fine for me ..
and i also fetch upto 6 image form parse data base.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("subclass");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> List, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e == null) {
                // success
                if (List.size() > 0) {
                    for (ParseObject parseObject : List) {
                        // here fetch image like..
                        ParseFile image = (ParseFile) parseObject.get("fieldName");

                        if (image != null) {
                            Log.e("getting Image", "Image URL " + image.getUrl());
                            // here add to your adapter array
                        }
                    }
                    // and here call your adapter for fill array data
                }
            } else {
                // e.getMessage() here getting error ...
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: and u want to load this image so use Picasso library for show image in image view.